# How to update a time taken from the internet in Android?

Tags: java, android

Hello I'm getting time from the internet and I would like my app to maintain it and update it throughout it's life, maybe using a background service? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Do you mean time from a service like NTP?

Comment: Yes, the actual time, not the device time, because it's not safe

Comment: In what sense is the device time not safe? Do you mean because the system clock is not monotonic?

Comment: Because the user can change it and in order to upload their post I need the actual time

Comment: Store the current system uptime with your time from the internet and calculate the difference any time you need a new trusted timestamp: [`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime())

Comment: I would love some code (: haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know how to get the current time in ms from the internet once

```
public class TrustedTime {
    private static long internetTime;
    private static long updateTime;

    /** this needs to happen once */
    public static void updateInternetTime(long time) {
        updateTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        internetTime = time;
    }

    public static long currentTimeMillis() {
        long sinceUpdate = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - updateTime;
        return internetTime + sinceUpdate;
    }
}
```

It's just a matter of simple math, calculating the difference between when the internet time was valid and now.

But if you really need to trust the time don't use client time at all. You can not trust client software. When you upload something, there is a server that has a local trusted time the user can't tamper with, use that instead. In other words, there is no need to send a timestamp for the client because the server knows the current time.